# TD, TH with no content always 0 height in Internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I discovered that in IE if a TD or TH has no content, it is considered 0 by 0 pixels in size.  In Chrome, its height is calculated based on the height of the row, whose height is determined based on the contents of the row.

I realized this because I was trying to add an `:after` pseudo-element to a TH element that did not have content.  In Chrome, the pseudo-element spanned the height of the row, but in IE, it was only a few pixels high.

I tried putting an `&nbsp;` in the TD, and that got me part of the way, but because my TH had a rowspan of 2, IE only calculated the height as 1 line of text, not the full height of the row.

Is this something that can be worked around in IE?

```
.test
{
    position: relative;
}

.test:after
{
    width: 5px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    content: ' ';
    background-color: #007bff;
}
```

Comment: which one of the IE?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - 10 and 11 for sure.  Works well in FireFox, Chrome, and Edge

Answer (score 1):

Just insert:

```
&nbsp;
```

To the empty TD or TH elements.

Comment: I've done that, but because the TH is rowspan=2, IE calculates the height as a single line, not the height of the actual row, so the pseudo element still only appears as partial height.

Comment: I try to make a test with elbrant's code and looks like it is working as expected. Here is code: https://textuploader.com/d85xn here is output: https://i.postimg.cc/VN3sbWXx/86.png Can you please share your output. so that we can try to compare the both results may help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either use `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, or insert an empty gif  to provide stability in the design.  A "shim" is just a 1px square image that is transparent and can be adjusted (by width and height) as needed.
Can you find the shim " [image: A "shim" or "spacer" gif] " between these quotes?
Before the days of `<div>` and responsive layout, tables ruled webdesign. If you wanted to make a solid line, you could put a shim inside your table row/column, designate the color of the `<td>` and use a spacer or shim image coded for the desired height and width. Doing this allowed your webpage load faster, because the image was <=1kb, which was a critical consideration during those days of dialup access.

Comment: You don't need to wrap it in a p tag, just the nonbreakingspace is enough